# Laravel 5.4 Image Uploading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am new to Laravel and want to learn image uploading. I used to do it very easily with Codeigniter but I am finding it hard in Laravel.

Following is what I used to do in Codeigniter:

```
$prof_pic = $_FILES['profile_pic']['name'];


        if($prof_pic != '') 
        {
        $config = array ('upload_path' => './images/students/',
                         'allowed_types' => "jpeg|jpg|png",
                         'overwrite' => TRUE,
                         'file_name' => str_replace(' ','-',$Maxtype."-".$fname."-".$lname)
                        );

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('profile_pic');

        $extension = pathinfo($prof_pic);
        $ext = $extension['extension'];

        $image = str_replace(' ','-',$config['file_name'].".".$ext);

        } else {
        $image = 'no_pic.jpg';  
        $ext = 'jpg';
        }
```

Is there any way to use this code in Laravel? I tried the following code in Laravel but it is showing some error.

```
$this->validate($request, ['company_logo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:1024',]);

            $imageName = time().'.'.$request->company_logo->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $request->company_logo->move(public_path('company_logo'), $imageName);

            return back()->with('success','Record Created');
```

This is the error:

```
LogicException in MimeTypeGuesser.php line 135:
Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)
```

Comment: I highly suggest using the laravel documentation before coming here, it is very detailed. For file uploads, https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#storing-uploaded-files

Comment: You learn by reading the docs or watching laracasts.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following Blog page, which might help you.
[Click here](http://www.techalyst.com/links/read/72/facebook-like-profile-photo-upload-in-laravel-5-using-jquery-croppic-plugin)